# How to resolve " org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/" with google driver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am facing above mentioned issue since 1 week. Earlier it was working smoothly. Even now sometimes it works fine but most of the time I am getting "**Failed to connect to localhost**/" error. :( 
I have upgraded chrome driver to 2.37 now downgraded it again to 2.36 but no luck. :( Thanks.

**Issue details:**
 **java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:4321
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:33:15.31Z'
System info: host: 'GURWUNknjk', ip: '10.202.126.154', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver**

Here is code for your reference:
Note : It works fine till login. Issue comes only when I try to search some element after login.

```
    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "d://chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        String url = "https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?continue=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.google.com%2Fb%2F0%2FAddMailService&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=AddSession";
        driver.get(url);

driver.manage().window().maximize();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15,TimeUnit.SECONDS) ;

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("input[type='Email']")));

        if(driver.getCurrentUrl().contains("https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?"))
        {

            driver.findElement(By.id("identifierId")).sendKeys(username);
            driver.findElement(By.id("identifierNext")).click();        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.name("password"))); 
            driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys(pwd);
            driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
        }
        else{
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("input[type='Email']")));
            driver.findElement(By.name("Email")).sendKeys(UserName);
            driver.findElement(By.id("next")).click();           wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.name("Passwd")));
            driver.findElement(By.name("Passwd")).sendKeys(Pwd);
                    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.name("signIn")));
 driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();
           }
wait.until(ExpectedConditions
                    .visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id(element id)));
            driver.findElement(By.id(element id))
            .sendKeys(some value);
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            driver.findElement(By.id(element id)).click(); }
```

Comment: Which chrome version you are using

Comment: Try: `driver = new ChromeDriver(new ChromeOptions());`

Comment: Also, remove the maximize line - it will fail.  If you really need to have it start maximized, you need to create an instance of ChromeOptions and add that as an option before instantiating the driver.

Comment: @AnkurSingh So far I have used 2.36 and 2.37.. I am facing issues in both version.

Comment: @BillHileman did both things but no luck. :(
Issue still persists

Answer (score 1):

The error says it all :

```
java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:4321 
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:33:15.31Z' 
System info: host: 'GURWUNknjk', ip: '10.202.126.154', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_131' 
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
```

The error clearly shows that the *ChromeDriver* was not recognized as in :

```
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
```

Your main issue is the **version compatibility** between the binaries you are using as follows :

- You are using *chromedriver=2.37*
- Your *chrome* version is unknown to us.
- Your *Selenium Client* version is **3.11.0**.
- Your *JDK version* is **1.8.0_131** which is pretty ancient.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *JDK v8u131* , *Selenium Client v3.11.0* , *ChromeDriver* version (*v2.37*).

### Solution

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u162**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u162-relnotes-4021436.html).
- Keep *ChromeDriver* at  current [**ChromeDriver v2.37**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version at ***Chrome v65.x*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.37 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.37/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test`.

Comment: Hey thanks for your comment.. :) For the same Java version it was working fine earlier. Anyway I will get it installed by Monday. 
I saw your comment on one post and performed most of the steps but issue still persists.
As of now I am using chrome version of "Version 65.0.3325.181 (Official Build) (64-bit)"

Comment: It worked after updating java version. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Sorry but issue still persists..:(
Like I said sometime it work sometime it doesn't
Now i do not know what is causing this issue..:(
Error details :

Error is java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:17498
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:33:15.31Z'
System info: host: 'GURWUNI5F3291', ip: '10.203.166.154', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_162'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at where you are instantiating the drive.
You wrote:  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "d://chromedriver.exe");

I believe the issue is with the chrome drive path. 
Try: "D:/chromedriver.exe");

There should be only one forward slash when defining the path.

Comment: Shouldn't windows path be \ instead of /  ? i.e. d:\chromedriver.exe

Comment: Try using the forward slash (/). I had the same issue and switch out the slash and it works fine now.